# "Installing" programs

Tags: software-installation

This is problem I encounter many times. Sometimes when I download programs, they are in zip/tar.gz or any other extension. I simply extract them and click on bin. Everything is working fine, but I want a program to be visible in unity search, be able to run it from terminal as "programname" and everything else I can do with programs installed from repository.

I don't want to edit bashrc, I believe it has to do something with links.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually there is a special "Ubuntu" version of Linux programs 
(.deb files or PPA repositories)
Which can be installed. Otherwise do this:

For just yourself:
put the program dir anywhere and create a launcher in ~/.local/share/applications/
which adds it to unity.

For others, you can do this for all users:
As root copy the folder to /opt (terminal: sudo nautilus /opt/ and then Drag-Drop)
And create a Launcher in /usr/share/applications by copying a existing one and changing it.

Comment: Thanks, how to add terminal command for my program? I think I'll have to learn more about folder structure.

Comment: @user50992 Please create a separate question for this matter.